# Laravel Query Builder raw query with two FROM statements

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

my apologies if this question sounds a little boring for someone I really turn here because I have already tried to solve my problem in different ways and I have not been able to obtain good results.

I am trying to convert a `MySQL` query to `Laravel Query Builder`, I show you the query:

```
SELECT DAY(AAA.fecha_hora_entrada) as DAY, IFNULL(BBB.SALES, 0) SALES, IFNULL(BBB.NET, 0) NET
FROM (
         SELECT fecha_hora_entrada
         FROM (
                  SELECT MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), 1) +
                         INTERVAL (MONTH(NOW()) - 1) MONTH +
                         INTERVAL daynum DAY fecha_hora_entrada
                  FROM (
                           SELECT t * 10 + u daynum
                           FROM (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
                                (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
                           ORDER BY daynum
                       ) AS AA
              ) AS AA
         WHERE MONTH(fecha_hora_entrada) = MONTH(NOW())
     ) AS AAA
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT (DATE(fecha_hora_entrada)) AS fecha_hora_entrada, (SUM(neto)) AS NET, (COUNT(neto)) AS SALES
                    FROM t_derivados
                    GROUP BY DATE(fecha_hora_entrada)) BBB
                   ON AAA.fecha_hora_entrada = BBB.fecha_hora_entrada;
```

What I have tried so far is the following. So far I have managed to pass part of the `MySQL` query to `Query Builder`

```
public function salesYear()
    {
        return DB::table(DB::table(DB::table(DB::table(DB::table(null, null)
            ->selectRaw('0 t UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3'),'A')
            ->orderBy('daynum')
            ->selectRaw('t * 10 + u daynum'), 'AA')
            ->selectRaw('MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), 1) + INTERVAL (MONTH(NOW()) - 1) MONTH + INTERVAL daynum DAY fecha_hora_entrada'), 'AA')
            ->addSelect('fecha_hora_entrada')
            ->whereRaw('MONTH(fecha_hora_entrada) = MONTH(NOW())'), 'AAA')
            ->selectSub('DAY(AAA.fecha_hora_entrada)', 'DAY')
            ->selectSub('IFNULL(BBB.SALES, 0)', 'SALES')
            ->selectSub('IFNULL(BBB.NET, 0)', 'NET')
            ->leftJoinSub(DB::table('t_derivados')
                ->selectSub('DATE(fecha_hora_entrada)', 'fecha_hora_entrada')
                ->selectSub('SUM(neto)', 'NET')
                ->selectSub('COUNT(neto)', 'SALES')
                ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(fecha_hora_entrada)')), 'BBB', 'AAA.fecha_hora_entrada', 'BBB.fecha_hora_entrada')
            ->toSql();
    }
```

I know it's a bit boring to read everything .. but let's focus on the next sub-sentence:

```
SELECT t * 10 + u daynum
FROM (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
     (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
ORDER BY daynum
...
```

The truth is I have not found a way to add the second `FROM` to `Query Builder`

```
SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
...
```

Someone expert on the subject could help me please. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Just a word of advice, this question seems to be referring to the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries), not Eloquent.  Eloquent is an ORM for dealing with Models and their relationships, but you don't appear to be using Models. You might attract more responses if you word the question appropriately.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @matticustard You are correct. Sorry for my mistake. Is fixed now.